# Using webpack.config.js files for dependencies

Tags: webpack

I have ModuleA, which depends on ModuleB. Both are in separate git repositories. ModuleB has a `webpack.config.js` file, and it works fine when I run webpack in ModuleB's directory. However, when I run webpack from ModuleA's directory, it seems like ModuleB's `webpack.config.js` isn't getting used.

Is this supposed to work, or are you supposed to pre-bundle ModuleB and point ModuleA at that bundle?

(Specifically, I'm using the `webpack.config.js` file to exclude a submodule in ModuleB.)

Comment: Hi @zachb, did you get an answer to this question ? I am also confused by this actually

Answer (score -1):

You should have **only one webpack.config.js** in a project.
Inside that project, there can be various modules.

If Module A needs Module B. Then you should **import** Module B in module A.

E.g.

Module B (B.js)

```
export default class A{}
```

Module A (A.js)

```
import B from 'B';
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking about. ModuleB is a dependency in a different git repository. It needs its own webpack.config.js.